# Inform when the html element gets instantiated

Tags: javascript, html, observable

Lets assume that I expect a specific div element to be present in html file. Its set id for that div "one".

I want javascript to inform me (console.log for example) when that element is instantiated, and possibly to change the css of that div just before it gets rendered (width="100px" for example). If it happens that that specific div doesnt exist, do nothing or inform that that div element was not rendered when the page fully loaded.

I have heard that Observable is the way to get alerts when I expect something to happen, but can someone give me a direction of where to start building that code to work?

Edit. The reason for this?
I want to catch the ad when wants to pop, so I can mod the div that is ad.

Comment: How does this element get created? Provide a [mcve] and less hypotheticals

Comment: Have you tried using `MutationObserver`?

Comment: I don't really have the answer but, what's the use of this?

Comment: Tried to provide greater explanation in edit section of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right, you want to watch for `<div id="one" />` elements. Update the corresponding condition and query selector if you need to catch a different element.

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
    mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function (addedNode) {
      if (!addedNode.getAttribute) {
        return; // not an element node
      }
      if (addedNode.getAttribute('id') === 'one') { // replace with
                                                    // appropriate condition
        // found, do whatever
      }
      var nodes = addedNode.querySelectorAll('div[id=one]'); // replace with
                                                             // appropriate selector
      [].forEach.call(nodes, function (node) {
        // found, do whatever
      });
    });
  });
});

observer.observe(document.body, { // you might replace it with an appropriate
                                  //  more specific parent element
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try and experiment with this code template. Thanks again.

Comment: @Learnonhardway did you have a chance to try it?

Comment: I did, but it doesnt alerts when element is instantiated(showed for the first time), but works when I try and edit the element after its showed. I need code for first case :)

Comment: You can catch it only when it's added to DOM. But if you remove or hide it right after it's added, it should not be visible.

Comment: You can try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/jprogd/8dgynuc0/ Here `<div id="one">One</div>` and `<div id="two">Two</div>` are being added after the button is clicked, but you don't even see the first one, because it becomes hidden right away as it's added to DOM

Comment: Oh god. I actually miss-typed ID name. It was my mistake all along. Thank you Dmitry.